# how can i Show Search Time in Result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

hi i have search form and when i search item in database i want display time of search like google : [image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to create a new stopwatch start it before you do your search then stop it afterwards and print out the time it took.

```
Stopwatch Time = new Stopwatch();
Time.Start();
SearchDM();
Time.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Search Took: {0} Seconds", Time.Elapsed)
```

Comment: @Christopher Stevenson it is suggested to not use DateTime as according to MSDN it has a resolution of ~16ms whereas System.Diagnostics.StopWatch looks for high resolution Timers which can also be checked using the Stopwatch.IsHighResolution() method, allowing a more precise indicator of the time it took to run.

Comment: No its still useful its just not as accurate. If set True its accurate to microseconds(It is actually accurate to nanoseconds but that's pointless in most situations), you usually only have to worry about it not being True on much older CPU's I've never run into a situation that it is set to False

Answer (score 1):

[Take](http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/checking-execution-time-with-cnet-use-of-it-in-wssfwcsf/) the time when user hits the button then when result came back from your data access layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the current time twice:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
var results = SearchDB(searchArgs);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan searchTime = endTime - startTime;
Console.Writeline("Search Took: {0} milliSeconds", searchTime.Milliseconds);
```